# C# Dock Panel Suite

Tags: c#, docker, panel, docking, suite

How can I change the user interface of the dock panel suite in C#? I want to change the icons of the docking arrows. So when you change the posistion of the form, the icons that show the docking positions are different.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create your own theme based on existing ones and replace the relevant PNG images of your own.